# how to set the basic message properties for message in Rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq

i am using Rabbitmq Java client API.i want to set the Basic Properties for message and also get the message Id of the message.if possible please provide some code to understand the things.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While sending a message through java client usually it is publish to a channel like

```
 CHANNEL.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, QUEUE_ROUTING_KEY, MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN, "message".getBytes)
```

Here you can set message properties

You can get the msg by using a delivery agent 
You have to first bind the queue like this

```
 Channel channel = conn.createChannel();
      String exchangeName = "myExchange";
      String queueName = "myQueue";
      String routingKey = "testRoute"; 
      boolean durable = true;
      channel.exchangeDeclare(exchangeName, "direct", durable);
      channel.queueDeclare(queueName, durable,false,false,durable, null);
channel.queueBind(queueName, exchangeName, routingKey);
      boolean noAck = false;
      QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
      channel.basicConsume(queueName, noAck, consumer);
```

Then use delivey to get msg

```
QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery;
            try {
               delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();

            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
               continue;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it can be done:

```
int PERSISTENCE_MESSAGE = 2; // Persist message
String TEXT_MESSAGE = "text/plain";
String queueName = "QUE-1";

Channel channel = this.connection.createChannel();
channel.queueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);

// Build message properties
Map messageProps = new HashMap();
//messageProps.put("TIME_MSG_RECEIVED", time);
messageProps.put("SOURCE_SYS", "SRC1");
messageProps.put("DESTINATION_SYS", "DST1");

// Set message properties
AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder basicProperties = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder();
basicProperties.contentType(TEXT_MESSAGE).deliveryMode(PERSISTENCE_MESSAGE)
.priority(1).headers(messageProps);

channel.basicPublish("", queueName,  basicProperties.build(), message.getBytes());
System.out.println(" Sent message to RabbitMQ: '" + message + "'");
channel.close();
```